# if condition true, print 1st sentence and then print 2nd sentence it condition true

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a diff result like below from Python's diff lib-

```
-     "text": "abc xyz efg "
+     "text": "abc xyz efg"
-     "header": true,
?               ^^^

+     "header": false,
?               ^^^^

-     "text": "1.1  bacdefg"
-   },
-   {
-     "header": false,
-       "This is one example sentence which needs to be extracted."
?                                            --------------                                               -

+       "This is one example sentence which needs to be extracted."
?                                                                                                    +                                                                            ++++++++++

-       "This is one example sentence which needs to be extracted."
?                                              --------------                                      -

+       "This is one example sentence which needs to be extracted."
?                                                                    ++++++++++                          +

+     "header": true,
+     "text": "some text"
```

I need to extract lines on three ways-

1. which starts with "-" and the following line starts with "?" in a list named updated
2. which starts with "+" and no "?" in the consecutive sentence in a list named deleted
3. which starts with "-" and no "?" in the consecutive sentence in a list named inserted

header : true / false can be ignored

I am new to Python and I somehow managed to parse two PDFs to JSONs and do a diff using difflib but unable to write a for loop and if condition to look for the consecutive lines of only text fields.

EDIT-

```
diffile=[]
diff = difflib.Differ()    
for line in diff.compare(f1_text, f2_text):
         #json.dump(line,f, indent=2)
    if line.startswith(("-", "+", "?")):
       diffile.append(line)




updated=[]
for i in range(len(diffile) - 1):
    value = diffile[i:i+2]
    for line in value:
        if line.startswith (("-")) and line.startswith ("?"):
            updated.append (line)
```

I did the above but I am not able to extract only the next line starting with "?" after "-". It is giving me all the lines starting with "?".

Comment: what did you come up with?

Comment: Start with the first of the three requirements, get that to run, then expand. If you have specific questions, please come back and ask them here. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi: I have updated with my approach. Somehow I am getting all the lines that starts with "?". Alternatively, I tried to loop in the next sentence but it says it is not iterable.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: I did try to explore the first condition, I am able to extract the line that starts with "+", "-","?" individually but unable to get the consecutive line which starts with "?" to the one with "+" or "-".  I will go through the tour and How to ask guides. Thank you for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that your diff result is a string (and you have it stored in the `diff` variable), you could do something like the following:

```
diff = """
-     "text": "abc xyz efg "
+     "text": "abc xyz efg"
-     "header": true,
?               ^^^

+     "header": false,
?               ^^^^

-     "text": "1.1  bacdefg"
-   },
-   {
-     "header": false,
-       "This is one example sentence which needs to be extracted."
?                                            --------------                                               -

+       "This is one example sentence which needs to be extracted."
?                                                                                                    +                                                                            ++++++++++

-       "This is one example sentence which needs to be extracted."
?                                              --------------                                      -

+       "This is one example sentence which needs to be extracted."
?                                                                    ++++++++++                          +

+     "header": true,
+     "text": "some text"
"""

lines = diff.splitlines()
updated, deleted, inserted = [], [], []

lines = [line for line in lines if line.find('"header"') == -1]

for i in range(len(lines)):
    try:
        if lines[i+1].startswith('?'):
            if lines[i].startswith('-'):
                updated.append(lines[i])
        else:
            if lines[i].startswith('+'):
                deleted.append(lines[i])
            elif lines[i].startswith('-'):
                inserted.append(lines[i])
    except IndexError:
        continue
```

Having each one of the inserted, deleted and updated lines in each of the lists.

Comment: Thank you so much @revliscano, this works for me, but the for the updated list, I needed to keep the line starting with "?" as well as that highlights (underscores) the place of difference. 
I added updated.append(lines[I+1]) to the program and I am getting the highlights as well. I will analyze the results for proof reading and accept the answers if all good.

Comment: I stored my diff results as a list. Now after running this program, I am not getting the results with line split. when I try to do splitlines(), it is throwing an error saying its not allowed for lists.

Comment: `diffile=[]
diff = difflib.Differ()    
for line in diff.compare(f1_text, f2_text):
         #json.dump(line,f, indent=2)
    if line.startswith(("-", "+", "?")):
       diffile.append(line)
`
This is how I get my diff result

Comment: If you already have the list, then skip the part of splitlines(). splilines should be applied to a text (string) wih multiple lines in it. :-)

Comment: If you want to quickly test if my code is working for you, just do `lines = diffile` and run

Comment: Okay. I think it is because of how I have saving these lists to a json file.
`lists = (["updated", "deleted", "inserted"])

data = ({listname: globals()[listname] for listname in lists})
with open('diff_result.json', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
    print(data, file=outfile)`

Comment: Hmm... Isn't there a way for you to just get the output of the diff in the form of a string ? If so, then you're done!

Comment: Let me edit my answer so I can show you better what I mean

Comment: Thank You @revliscano. It was actually due to the way I was saving it. using json.dump() did the trick. :)